# How to check if geocode is close to or on path defined in a KML LineString with PHP or MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, maps, kml

I have a KML file defining several paths/routes (representing actual roads) enclosed in the `<LineString><coordinates></coordinates></LineString>` tags. Parsing the file to other formats (arrays/MySQL) is already in place, so that's not a problem.

Given a point (longitude/latitude) I would like to be able to check if the point is on or close to (within a few meters) one of the routes in the KML file. I've been looking for a solution in PHP, but I haven't been able to find one - and I'm not really sure, what I'm looking for. This does however seem to me like a common problem, so I suspect someone already solved the problem. Does anybody know of a solution? ;)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break this down into two problems:

- Generate a set of polygons from each section of your path.
- Do a simple point in polygon test on the above polygons.

There should be some php out there to accomplish those two tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

It took quite a lot of trial and error, but eventually I found a solution. Unfortunately pip tests seem to take quite some time, so I'll probably have to find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

`pnpoly` is actually quite fast if done correctly.  I wrote a check against many hundreds of thousands of polygon vertices in MySQL *well* under second processing.  Pulling the data into PHP and performing the pnpoly loop there can do it in not a whole lot more time.

Post the code you're using?